# How to verify an unbalanced table in Gherkin?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have some tests that verify table results, but on some tests my table structures are slightly different in that the column headers and rows are sometimes 'unbalanced', meaning I have 5 column headers on row 1 but the subsequent rows have 6 columns.  An example is like this:

```
|        |  |  |  |  |  
|    |   |  |  |  |  |
```

The header row's first column aligns with the second row's first two columns, structurally, but cucumber sees this as an unbalanced table, expecting less columns on the second row in order to match the header row.  Is there a way to tell Cucumber/Gherkin to ignore these kinds of differences?

Answer (score 0):

I don't there is a way to ignore your unbalance.

I would use two different scenarios.